# Lambda including dependencies on node_modules

Tags: lambda, node-modules

I'm new to Lambda and am trying to figure out how to deploy dependencies on node_modules.  Please note I am not using Serverless.  I am using webpack to bundle my Lambda function.

The first thing I thought of doing was to just bundle the node_module dependencies as part of the webpack build process as one file.  But then I figured out this is not a good thing?  Next option I have is to copy the corresponding dependent node module into the lambda deployment zip folder.  But the problem/question I have here is

1. Is this the standard way of deploying the dependencies?
2. If my dependency is dependent on another dependency lets say dependency2 then how do I know this and do I need to copy this across as well?
3. Is there any other standard way of doing thing which I have missed?

Comment: Olden days! As of today you can use Lambda Layers to bundle up all your dependencies and upload them in on central Lambda Layer and all your Lambda Functions will be able to magically import them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the standard way of deploying the dependencies?

The standard way is to upload a zip package containing your handler file and `node_modules` directory if necessary.

The webpack way would be to create a single javascript file bundle that already includes all the dependencies in one file (in most simple cases). If you have dependencies that are dependent on native bindings (e.g. `bcrypt`), you can exclude them from webpack, and you can include `bcrypt` normally in a `node_modules` directory.

> If my dependency is dependent on another dependency lets say dependency2 then how do I know this and do I need to copy this across as well?

Using the standard way, `npm` would already handle these dependencies for you. So, all you have to do is to include your `node_modules` inside your deployment package.

Using `webpack`, it handles this for you. Just learn to configure it properly.

As a minimal example for a webpack config, you can use this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    handler: './handler.js',
  },
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
};
```